# \vspace with negative value not working as expected

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to position the image exactly in the corner of the margins, regardless of the text. However, the "Foo" gets placed slightly lower when using the code between the %s. Comment it out and you'll see what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

%
\begin{raggedleft}
    \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{portrait} \\
\end{raggedleft}
\vspace{-0.2\textheight}
%

\begin{cv}{Foo}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

I tried this solution, since picins isn't shipped with TeX Live and thus

```
\parpic[r]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{portrait}}
```

doesn't work. Wrapfig didn't work either.

Is there an easy fix using vspace?

Comment: The space is because `F` is not too high to fill the whole line height. Test with `{Foo \rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the generic set of macros `\insbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\input{insbox}
\makeatletter
\@InsertBoxMargin = 5mm
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-6ex}
\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{loupnorstein1}} %
\vspace{0.65\baselineskip}
\begin{cv}{Foo}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]